# Installing Ubuntu Desktop on usb stick

Tags: live-usb

trying to install Ubuntu Desktop on a USB stick but I do not succeed.

First time I tried, the USB stick contained an installation of USB server and I wanted to start over again. However, it complained about partioning.

Removed all the partitions from the stick and tried again, hoping that the installer would help me out with partioning... But now the USB stick did not show up at all...

Created one partion NTFS on the USB stick and tried again but the only "automated" alternative I get for installing is to overwrite or add Ubuntu to my HDD which already contains Windows, something that I do not want...

Do I need to manually create partions on the stick in the installer? Which partitions should I create? The USB stick is 8GB and the machine that I will test it on has 8GB memory.

Helpful for any support here.

Regards, Tobbe G

Comment: Do you have Windows in the same 8GB USB stick you want to install Ubuntu? If not, overwrite it. **Do not overwrite your HDD!**

Comment: According to the documentation, the USB stick should be formatted as FAT32, not as NTFS.

Comment: use a tool like Etcher. Its like Rufus. http://etcher.io

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by using the usb-creator-gtk tool (also called Startup Disk Creator) in Ubuntu. All you need is an Ubuntu cd image somewhere on your Ubuntu machine

In the Startup Disk Creator tool, just choose how much "reserved extra space" needs to be used to save documents and settings. This option appears in the first screen that this tool shows.

Then, you can boot your laptop or other computer from this USB disk, and use it like a normal computer - your documents can be stored on USB and used later.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to mention here is that if you want Ubuntu 12 on a USB and if you are going to use the Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator, make you use Ubuntu 12, because if you use Ubuntu 10, you'll have problems. Same goes with Ubuntu 10, make sure you have Ubuntu 10 if you are going to make a Ubuntu 10 USB disk.